# MetadataService read LeadConvertSettings

Tags: metadata-api, lead-conversion

I'm trying to access LeadConvertSettings via MetadataService class but it's not working properly.

```
List<MetadataService.LeadConvertSettings> result;
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
MetadataService.IReadResult readResult = service.readMetadata('LeadConvertSettings', new List<String>{'Lead'});
result = (List<MetadataService.LeadConvertSettings>) readResult.getRecords(); 
System.debug('** ' + JSON.serialize(result));
```

If I put a null or empty list as second parameter for **readMetadata** it gives me an error. With the previous piece of code it's giving me the following:

```
[{"fullName_type_info":["fullName","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema","string","0","1","false"],"fullName":null,"field_order_type_info":["fullName"],"apex_schema_type_info":["http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata","true","false"],"type_att_info":["xsi:type"],"type":"LeadConvertSettings","opportunityCreationOptions_type_info":["opportunityCreationOptions","http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata",null,"0","1","false"],"opportunityCreationOptions":null,"objectMapping_type_info":["objectMapping","http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata",null,"0","-1","false"],"objectMapping":null,"fullName_type_info":["fullName","http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata",null,"0","1","false"],"fullName":null,"field_order_type_info":["fullName","allowOwnerChange","objectMapping","opportunityCreationOptions"],"apex_schema_type_info":["http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata","true","false"],"allowOwnerChange_type_info":["allowOwnerChange","http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata",null,"0","1","false"],"allowOwnerChange":null}]
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Or is this even achievable?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass it's **fullName** in the second parameter which is **LeadConvertSettings**. So if you update the line like below it will return the Lead Convert Settings correctly.

```
MetadataService.IReadResult readResult = service.readMetadata('LeadConvertSettings', new List<String>{'LeadConvertSettings'});
```